# What does this mean: "C:\users\temp.username.001>" on the cmd prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Has anybody ever seen this in their in command prompt?  What does it mean?

```
C:\Users\Temp.Username.001>
```

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows `cmd.exe` will open in the user's profile directory, whose name is held in the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable.

When a new user is created, but a profile directory already exists with the same name, then the profile directory will be created with `.001` appended to the username. This can happen when a user is deleted, but its profile is preserved, and then that user is added again.

If the user (or the profile) was not properly deleted, it could be that some related settings are still found on the pc, possibly in the system registry. In this case, when profile recreation is attempted, an inconsistent state is detected, and a *temporary* profile is used, which is not preserved across subsequent sessions.

So it appears that the user you have logged in with has its profile in `C:\Users\Temp.Username.001` and cmd.exe by default sets the prompt to the current directory. This is why the prompt is as it is.

Comment: Your answer explains the `Username.001` part, but not the `Temp.Username` part. `Temp` is added when for some reason the profile is temporary, i.e. its contents are not going to be preserved between logins. This happened to me once after I deleted some profiles from advanced system settings and something was not completely removed. I had to delete the leftover registry keys.

Comment: @simlev Thanks - feel free to edit answers as well as questions.  It all helps, it isn't rude!

Comment: Let me just elaborate what happened. The pc was not realy mine but from my coworker. This is what happened, She turned on the pc and try to open a program and when she tried to login to the program she cannot connect and ask me to help her connect to the program. the program's database is located in another computer and to connect to the db we mapped a network drive, drive z:\.

Comment: when i check the my computer i did not find the drive z so i created it again and able to connect to the program. after i created drive z: i also connected the pc to the printer that was connected to another computer, actually 2 printers i added in 2 different pc's in the network. after that i left and go back to my work. the lady who used the pc told me later that the other pc's in the network cannot connect to the printer when they already are connected to it the previous day. that was the time i found out about the topic above. usually in the command prompt it is always C:\Users\Username>

Comment: and the files in the desktop and the download and my document foldders files are missing. i do not know what was being done in the pc the previous day.

Comment: @MadangTimbers You should find your Desktop, Documents and Download folders in the `C:\users\<user> folder`; make a copy of any data you want to retain. Then you may delete the profile, delete the user and recreate the user.